# Ocaml error lwt

Tags: ocaml

The following

```
let new_socket () = Lwt_unix.socket Unix.PF_INET Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0 in  
let socket_address = Network.make_address "127.0.0.1" 7777 in  
let listening_socket = new_socket () in  
Lwt_unix.setsockopt listening_socket Unix.SO_REUSEADDR true;  
Lwt_unix.bind listening_socket socket_address;
```

results into this error:

Error: correctness:2:remote_client:0:set

```
Unix.Unix_error(Unix.EADDRINUSE, "bind", "")
Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 782, characters 22-23
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 34, characters 8-18
Called from file "src/oUnit.ml", line 597, characters 6-10`
```

Last line fails to grant the bind, ideas why, how to pass this?

Answer (score 3):

The error is clearly stated: the address you are trying to bind to is already in use, a socket is is already bound on port 7777.

To understand the codes of the `Unix_error` raised by a function look in the manual of the corresponding C unix function, in that case [bind(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html).

Comment: I need this port, so what should I do?

Comment: if you need the port, try to figure out which process is using it, and stop it. If you need to have that process running, you can try to change its settings to use a different port, therefore freeing the port for your own use. If you cannot do the above, try finding a different computer to run your programme.